# error setting nr_hugepages via SYSFS

Tags: memory-management, linux-kernel, huge-pages

I have 8G of physical memory, Fedora20, and configured kernel parameters to allocate two 1G hugepages at boot-up time by passing the following parameters to the kernel:

```
default_hugepagesz=1G hugepagesz=1G hugepages=2
```

HugeTLBFS is auto mounted:

```
% mount | grep ^huge
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
%
```

Upon reboot, all looks good, and I see the kernel has allocated the required pages:

```
% dmesg | grep HugeTLB
HugeTLB registered 1 GB page size, pre-allocated 2 pages
% grep -E ^"(Mem|Huge)" /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:        8137732 kB
MemFree:         5359672 kB
MemAvailable:    5707656 kB
HugePages_Total:       2
HugePages_Free:        2
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:    1048576 kB
%
```

As you see the amount of free memory should allow me to increase number of hugepages, however I fail to do so:

```
% echo 3 > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages
-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
```

or

```
% echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages
-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument
%
```

Also decreasing the number of pages fail. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I have found the reason of this behaviour. The kernel documentation for "hugepagesz=" parameter in https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt says that **"1GB pages can only be allocated at boot time using hugepages= and not freed afterwards"** I think this is why I can't decrease number of pages.

Also, the code in mm/hugetlb.c doesn't allow this operation:

```
#if defined(CONFIG_CMA) && defined(CONFIG_X86_64)
...
static inline bool gigantic_page_supported(void) { return true; }
#else
static inline bool gigantic_page_supported(void) { return false; }
...
#endif
...
static int hugetlb_sysctl_handler_common(...)
{
  ...
  if (write && hstate_is_gigantic(h) && !gigantic_page_supported())
          return -EINVAL;
  ...
}
```

So, unless CONFIG_CMA is defined (and in the default kernel configuration shipped with Fedora 20 this option is disabled), the kernel will always return EINVAL.

Comment: Yep, for 2M pages I do not see this error. For 1G I do. So, concur.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you may require superuser permissions for the command. Alternatively, you could try the below step if you want to make changes persistent on your system.

First its required to mount the hugetlbfs for traditional hugepages to work.

```
mkdir /hugetlbfs
mount -t hugetlbfs none /hugetlbfs
```

Note: IA-64 supports - 4KiB, 2MiB and 4MiB pages
Note: x86_64 supports - 4KiB, 2MiB, 4MiB or 1GiB pages

Next, depending on your requirement, edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` file and specify the number of hugepages in the nr_hugepages:

```
vm.nr_hughpages=2
```

Now run the command `sysctl -p` for the configuration changes to take effect. Note: if your requirement of number of huge pages are large and no contiguous free blocks available, then its recommended to restart the system after the above changes.

To check if the number of hugepages have been allocated, use `cat /proc/meminfo | grep Huge`

```
HugePages_Total:    2
HugePages_Free:     2
HugePages_Rsvd:     0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

Comment: I run all commands with root privileges, and basically I did the same set of configuration as you described. Setting vm.nr_hughpages with sysctl fails (setting key "vm.nr_hugepages": Invalid argument). The max hugepages I was able to set is 5, although I configured hugepages=6 as kernel parameter, I think the kernel didn't allow and set it to 5.

Comment: By the way, what is the difference between interfaces /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages and /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-1048576kB/nr_hugepages? They seem to tune the same parameter?

Comment: @Mark What is the size of the hugepages you have configured ? What are the error in the syslog ? Did you try to restart the system are setting the nr_hugepages, maybe you system does not have sufficient free memory ?

Comment: Well both are pseudo file systems, /proc/ - is meant to export process information, while /sys is meant to export information on devices, drivers and other sub-systems. Read [link](http://people.ee.ethz.ch/~arkeller/linux/multi/kernel_user_space_howto-2.html)

Comment: I have edited my original post and provided more details. Please review it.

Comment: Looks like you are setting the hugepages=2, but of size 1GB for each contiguous block which is probably not available on your system therefore, you need to use /etc/sysctl.conf and reboot the system to this could be preall0cated, and set the nr_hugepages like I have described in the above post. For small page sizes, try using /proc entries instead "echo 20 > /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages". please read the link provided earlier to understand the diff between /proc and /sys. Also setting it through the /etc/sysctl.conf is more persistent across reboots.

Comment: I have no problems setting up to 5x1G hugepages via kernel parameters, this method is persistent, however I can't change the numbers on the running system once the system has booted and allocated the pages.